# Meteor method updating several collections refresh the client

Tags: meteor

In my application I rate applications relatively to a question. So I have 3 collections : apps, questions & rates. 
When I insert a rate in my db, **I also check if all questions have been answered for an application. If so, I update an attribute *ratingComplete* of the current application :**

```
Meteor.methods({
    rateApplication: function(rateAttributes){
        var user = Meteor.user();
        var rateAlready = Rates.findOne({appId: rateAttributes.appId, qId: rateAttributes.qId});

        // ... some checks & code ...

        if(rateAlready !== undefined)
            Rates.remove({_id: rateAlready._id});

        rateId = Rates.insert(note);

        if(Rates.find({appId:rateAttributes.appId}).count() === Questions.find().count()){
            Applications.update({_id:rateAttributes.appId},{$set:{ratingComplete:true}});
        }

        return rateId;
    }
});
```

It works well except when this part of the code occurs :

```
if(Rates.find({appId:rateAttributes.appId}).count() === Questions.find().count()){
            Applications.update({_id:rateAttributes.appId},{$set:{ratingComplete:true}});
}
```

If this happens, the work is done but **the client page refresh. Even if I put a e.preventDefault() in my Template event.**

Anyone knows why and how I can avoid that?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: My guess is because you are updating the `_id` attribute of the collection object. I would suggest having a different key value pair in `Applications` where you store that `rateAttributes.appId`. Let me know if this fixes your problem.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not understand but I am not updating the `_id` attribute. I'm just catching the good application with `_id` but only updating the `ratingComplete` attribute.

Comment: try checking out https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform. On Form submit you can specify calling a meteor method to complete all the validation and complete new updates. It should also handle the refresh issue.